# How do I add another .mdf file at a different location and write data to it - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a huge SQL Server archival database (`MISArchival`): 250GB and it's sitting on a `E:\` drive which has only 30GB space left.

I have to purge/move out some more data from production MIS database to this archival database (`MISArchival`).

Now I have another drive which is `I:\` drive and have around 200GB of space.

My question is: how can I make/add another `.mdf` file on `I:\` drive and make sure next time I insert data to this archival database, it starts to write to this new `.mdf` file created on the `I:\` drive and NOT to the `E:\` drive ?

Current setup:

```
E:\Database\Data\BSP_MIS_Archived.mdf
E:\Database\Log\BSP_MIS_Archived.ldf
```

I need another `.mdf` file at a different location due to space issue:

```
I:\Database\Data\BSP_MIS_Archived_2.mdf
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't move objets between files throuth some statement. You will need to move the data your self.

Firt of all create a `filegroup` and add a new file to it at the new drive.

Create a new table with the same script as the original but using the new filegroup move the data using a `insert/select` comando or `BCP/Bulk` and rename the table `sp_rename`

In the end you need to do a shrink at the original file.

If you have more doubts add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add data files from the database properties in SSMS or from code:

```
use master;
go

ALTER DATABASE MISArchival
ADD FILE 
(
    NAME = MISArchival2,
    FILENAME = 'I:\Database\Data\BSP_MIS_Archived_2.ndf'
);
go
```

Some things to note:

- Typically the secondary data files have an NDF extension but that's not required
- If you don't create a separate filegroup then the extra data files will be placed into PRIMARY
- You need to consider what the appropriate initial size, max size, and growth requirements are for your database

Ref: [MSSQL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/add-data-or-log-files-to-a-database)